# how to change texts using jquery / javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using the code below to change some text on the page. its working fine but it only changes single words. When I want to change a whole sentence the code gives an error.  Can you help me I am not very good with javascript/jquery. Thanks.

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
    function recursiveReplace(node) {
        if (node.nodeType == 3) { // text node
            node.nodeValue = node.nodeValue.replace("1d", "1 day");
            node.nodeValue = node.nodeValue.replace("2d", "2 days");
            node.nodeValue = node.nodeValue.replace("will expire in Unlimited", "will not expire");
            return;
        }

        if (node.nodeType == 1) { // element
            $(node).contents().each(function () {
                recursiveReplace(this);
            });
        }
    }

    recursiveReplace(document.body);
});
```

Comment: What error? Can you provide a fiddle? The example you gave is working fine. You can see it working here: http://jsfiddle.net/andreortigao/2pg8vwtr/

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Please see: 
http://jsfiddle.net/2pg8vwtr/1/

Comment: You should probably post the HTML markup in your question, just for future reference.

Comment: The problem is `<b>Unlimited</b>`, if you remove bold tags it works.

Comment: Is it not possible to solve this without removing the bold tag.

Answer (score 0):

The error you are experiencing is not due to words/sentences. It is because your HTML has bold tags around the word Unlimited. Therefore, it couldn't find a string the matched "will expire in Unlimited". If the last line of your HTML looks like this:

```
<span>1d 2d will expire in Unlimited</span>
```

I don't know what you want the final outcome to be, but this fiddle replaces the entire string:

```js
$(document).ready(function() { 
     function recursiveReplace(node) {
    if (node.nodeType == 3) { // text node
        node.nodeValue = node.nodeValue.replace("1d", "1 day");
        node.nodeValue = node.nodeValue.replace("2d", "2 days");
        node.nodeValue = node.nodeValue.replace("will expire in Unlimited", "will not expire");

        return;
    }

    if (node.nodeType == 1) { // element
        $(node).contents().each(function () {
            recursiveReplace(this);
        });
    }
}

recursiveReplace(document.body);
     });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span>1d</span>
<span>2d</span>
<span>will expire in Unlimited</span>
<br />
<span>1d 2d will expire in Unlimited</span>
```

Good Luck.

Comment: hi! the text is not static and this is repeating like100 times for example 1 day, 2 days, 3 days, unlimited... I can't remove the bold tag. Is it not possible to solve this without removing the bold tag?